# Photoshop plugin icons display correctly on one computer/Photoshop version, but not another. Why?

Tags: icons, adobe, manifest, photoshop

I'm testing my plugin on two different computers + Photoshop versions, and for some reason, on one of them, the plugin icons work + display correctly -- but on the other, they don't show up at all.

Here's the pertinent section of the manifest code + file structure:

```
    "manifestVersion": 4,
    "host": {
        "app": "PS",
        "minVersion": "22.0.0"
    },
    "icons": [
        { "width": 23, "height": 23, "path": "icons/layers-icon-23x23.png", "scale": [ 1, 2 ], "theme": [ "dark", "darkest" ], "species": [ "generic" ] },
        { "width": 23, "height": 23, "path": "icons/layers-icon-23x23-black.png", "scale": [ 1, 2 ], "theme": [ "lightest", "light" ], "species": [ "generic" ] }
    ],
    "entrypoints": [
        {
            "type": "panel",
            "id": "main",
            "label": {
                "default": "Test Plugin v1"
            },
            "icons": [
                {"width":23,"height":23,"path":"icons/layers-icon-23x23.png","scale":[1,2],"theme":["darkest","dark","medium"]},
                {"width":23,"height":23,"path":"icons/layers-icon-23x23-black.png","scale":[1,2],"theme":["lightest","light"]}
            ],
            "minimumSize": {"width": 290, "height": 200},
            "maximumSize": {"width": 290, "height": 600},
            "preferredDockedSize": {"width": 230, "height": 300},
            "preferredFloatingSize": {"width": 290, "height": 400}
        }
    ],
```

Then my image filenames, in the "icons" folder itself, are as follows:

layers-icon-23x23@1x.png
layers-icon-23x23-black@1x.png

Works fine on one computer, which is Photoshop version 22.4.2. Does not work on another computer, which is Photoshop version 23.5.2. I tried updating the computer using the newer Photoshop version to the most recent 24.7.0 release, to see if it was a bug specific to 23.5.2. Still no luck, and I continue to have the same issue -- the plugin icons do not appear. Any idea why?

Thanks!